# About $make conan_deps when installing Space Veins, an extension of Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, conan, sumo

I have tried to install Space Veins and run the command according to the official web page, but it fails.
The log of the process is as follows.

> user@ubuntu:~/space_veins$ make conan_deps
> make: *** No rule to make target 'conan_deps'.  Stop.

Other software versions are as follows

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Veins 5.1
- OMNeT++ 5.6.2
- SUMO 1.8.0
- Conan 1.42.1 (A C/C++ package manager required to install PROJ 8.1.1)

[Space Veins Installation](https://sat.car2x.org/documentation/installation/)

The file conan_deps did not exist in the Space Veins directory. Therefore, I ran $make makefiles, $make without running $make conan_deps, but the tutorial still did not work.

Comment: I have no idea how that project works, but it is likely that the installation of dependencies didn't succeed. You need to specify all the previous steps you did, like ``conan install``, etc., that would help. Also need to guarantee that you installed the right Conan version. It might happen that Conan 1.42 is nowadays a bit outdated that Conan 2.0 has been out for a while, and packages from ConanCenter might stop working for older versions of Conan.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint. The tutorial on the website is supposed to work for space_Veins-0.2. There are a lot of changes in the master branch that are not yet reflected on the website. I am sorry for the inconveniences.

In the last weeks space_Veins changed a lot and I am planning to publish a new release within the next two weeks which will improve the build process and reduce dependencies. For example, conan will not be a dependency anymore. Afterwards I will update the website such that the tutorial will work again.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Perhaps the reason is that the file downloaded by "$git clone https://github.com/veins/space_veins.git" was not space_Veins-0.2.
However, when I download space_Veins-0.2 and execute "$make conan_deps", an error occurs.

Comment: FYI @KEI , I just released space_Veins 0.3. It provides support for Singularity and VS Code Dev Containers (Docker). Further, there is an updated [installation guide](https://sat.car2x.org/documentation/installation).